# Pandas rolling and transform when multiple rows have the same date

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['a','a','a','a','b','b'], 'dt': ['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-02','2016-01-03', '2016-01-05','2016-01-06'], 'val': [1,33,45,3,2,1]})

  user          dt  val
0    a  2016-01-01    1
1    a  2016-01-02   33
2    a  2016-01-02   45
3    a  2016-01-03    3
4    b  2016-01-05    2
5    b  2016-01-06    1
```

I want to have an extra column which shows the aggregated values grouped by each user for the past 2 days (on each row of the original dataset). So my desired output looks like the following:

```
  user          dt  val  sum
0    a  2016-01-01    1  1
1    a  2016-01-02   33  79
2    a  2016-01-02   45  79
3    a  2016-01-03    3  81
4    b  2016-01-05    2  2
5    b  2016-01-06    1  3
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```
x['sum'] = x.groupby(['user']).rolling('2d', on='dt')['val'].transform('sum')
```

Even without using transform it gives me an error saying:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Following your logic, all the rows of user a should be summed up since the difference in days is only 1

Comment: This is just a sample example. You can consider there are more than two dates for each group.

Comment: In your new example, for "user a" at 01-03, the last two days should be 33 + 45 + 3 = 81, no? How come it is 48?

Comment: @dgg32 you're right sorry. fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick and dirty solution, at least it works for your old and new examples.

```
###calculate date sum and make it into a dataframe
tmp = x.groupby(['user', "dt"])["val"].sum().to_frame("date_sum")

tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)

#### do the rolling. However, rolling will leave the first date as NaN
a = tmp.groupby("user")["dt", "date_sum"].rolling(2, on='dt')["date_sum"].sum().reset_index()

#### fill the first date NaN with data from tmp
a.loc[(a["user"] == tmp["user"]) & (a["dt"] == tmp["dt"]) & pd.isna(a["date_sum"]), "date_sum"] = tmp["date_sum"]

final = pd.merge(x, a, how="left", on=["user", "dt"])
final
```

Output:

```
    user    dt  val     date_sum
0   a   2016-01-01  1   1.0
1   a   2016-01-02  33  79.0
2   a   2016-01-02  45  79.0
3   a   2016-01-03  3   81.0
4   b   2016-01-05  2   2.0
5   b   2016-01-06  1   3.0
```

Comment: This does not match OP's output.

Comment: @dgg32 I wanted to keep the format of the original dataframe and add an extra column like how we normally do with transform. But transform does not work with rolling.

Comment: Thank you, I should merge the original so that the column "val" can be transfered.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close with your solution, you have to convert `dt` to `datetime`, plus you have to access the `numpy array` while assigning as column, since `GroupBy.rolling` will make a `MultiIndex` in this case.

This way the indices cannot be aligned:

```
x['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(x['dt'])
x['sum'] = x.groupby('user').rolling('2d', on='dt')['val'].sum().to_numpy()
```

```
  user         dt  val   sum
0    a 2016-01-01    1  1.00
1    a 2016-01-02   33 34.00
2    a 2016-01-02   45 79.00
3    a 2016-01-03    3 81.00
4    b 2016-01-05    2  2.00
5    b 2016-01-06    1  3.00
```

*Notice*: the difference in row 1, 2 is because this is a "rolling sum", so it will not be `79` in row 1.

Comment: In your solution, the second row has a sum 34, differing from his desired 79.

Comment: Read my "notice" on the bottom. Pretty confident that this is the output that OP wants.

Comment: Actually I wanted to have a daily sum for each row so that it shows the total sum of that date regardless of where in the dataframe it is. Do you know if there is any way to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you edit your desired output so it shows precisely what you want? This is quite confusing. @polaris9508

Comment: @Erfan I mean the output that I already had in the question which has 79 for the second row. That is what I am looking for.